# Confusion matrix shows two matrices instead of one

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, knn, confusion-matrix

CSV link for reproducing the issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eabh90asi7ocikp/KNN.csv

Hello, I want to ask a question

When i use kNN in Python like this:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
list_stopwords = stopwords.words('indonesian')
list_stopwords.extend(["yg", "dg", "rt", "dgn", "ny", "d", 'klo', 
                       'kalo', 'amp', 'biar', 'bikin', 'bilang', 'anjgg',
                      'gak', 'ga', 'krn', 'yang', 'nya', 'nih', 'sih', 'karna', 'karena',
                       'si', 'tau', 'tdk', 'tuh', 'utk', 'ya', 
                       'jd', 'jgn', 'sdh', 'aja', 'n', 't', 'halah','hilih', 'basmalah', 'bismilah','basmallah','bismillah',
                       'nyg', 'hehe', 'yg', 'pen', 'u', 'nan', 'loh', 'rt',
                       '&amp', 'yah','wah','wow','klu','insyaallah','dari','vpn',
                       'jadinya','saja','apapun','hai','bro','tes','test','dlu', 'lho', 'to',
                       'aku','lalu','sebelum','itupun','hingga','ah','eh','dapat','gus',
                       'gusssss','sehari','ahh','okey','okeey','tess','com','deh','sih','ini',
                       'ciee','ehh','pula','wah','ok','ko','na','mu','mah','duh','nge','vivo','hape', 'haha','hihu','hahaha'
                       'iya','halo','assalamualaikum','warahmatullah','hiwabarokatu','amin','hallo','atu', 'huhu', 'huhuhu', 'anjer', 'anjir', 'anjeng',
                       'abang','uc','oh','tolong','kah','laah','ig','jum','at','bal','mana','pun','boss', 'si','sih',
                       'nkri','alhamdulillah','jawa','barat','kalimantan', 'bismillahirrahmanirrahim','eehh','lyke','xixix','xixixi','wkwkwkwk','wkwk','wkwkw','wkwkkw','huehehehe','hehehe','hehe'])
print(list_stopwords)    
#Import Library

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as mumu
from sklearn import preprocessing, model_selection
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import matplotlib
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix as confusion_matrix
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from collections import Counter
data=mumu.read_csv("KNN.csv")
X=data['normalized']
Y=data['sentiment']
print(X.shape, Y.shape)
#TF-IDF
TF_IDF=TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=False, stop_words=list_stopwords)
X_TFIDF=TF_IDF.fit_transform(X)
print(X_TFIDF.shape)
print(X_TFIDF)
#TTS
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)
len(X_train)
#KNN Calculation
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()
ctmTr = cv.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_dtm = cv.transform(X_test)
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
knn.fit(ctmTr, Y_train)
knn_score = knn.score(X_test_dtm, Y_test)
print("Results for KNN Classifier with CountVectorizer")
print(knn_score)
Y_pred_knn = knn.predict(X_test_dtm)
print(Y_pred_knn)
#Confusion matrix
#tn, fp, fn, tp =
cm = confusion_matrix(Y_pred_knn, Y_test)
cr = classification_report(Y_pred_knn, Y_test)
print(cm)
print(cr)
con_mat=mumu.DataFrame(cm)
plt.title("KNN Confusion Matrix")
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.heatmap(con_mat, annot=True, cmap='Blues')
ax.set_title('Seaborn Confusion Matrix with labels\n\n');
ax.set_xlabel('\nPredicted Values')
ax.set_ylabel('Actual Values ');
## Ticket labels - List must be in alphabetical order
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['False','True'])
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['False','True'])
## Display the visualization of the Confusion Matrix.
plt.show()
```

The confusion matrix shows like this:

```
[[[25 34]
  [ 7 14]]

 [[14  7]
  [34 25]]]
```

And even the plotting library refuses to plot with reason:

```
Must pass 2-d input. shape=(2, 2, 2)
```

Is there anything wrong with my code and/or dataset? How do I fix it so the confusion matrix shows only one matrix instead of two?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `import pandas as mumu`. First time seeing that...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're importing `multilabel_confusion_matrix`. You only have binary labels in your `Y_pred`. If you import the standard `confusion_matrix`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
```

then you get a 2x2 confusion matrix:

```
[[11  6]
 [32 31]]
```

And your plotting code produces this:
[image]